# Randomly change color of a rectangle with mouse click

Tags: java, swing, graphics, mouselistener

I'm working on this code in which I need to draw a house. The house has a door(rectangle) that randomly changes color with a mouse click. Everything else besides the door doesn't change color at all.

How to make the color of the door change on mouse click?

```
package finalExam;  

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Final  extends JFrame{         

    public Final(){

        setTitle("An Interactive House");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setVisible(true);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g){


        int [] xCoords = { 40, 250, 460 };
        int [] yCoords = { 200, 50, 200 };

        super.paint(g);         

        g.drawRect(80, 200, 330, 260);

        g.drawPolygon(xCoords , yCoords , 3);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(190, 330, 100, 130);
        addMouseListener(new MouseEventListener());

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillOval(280, 400, 5, 5);


    }

    private class MouseEventListener implements MouseListener{

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0){

            repaint();

        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0){

        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0){

        }           
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0){

        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0){

        }
    }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            new Final();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't override `paint`, especially of a top level container like `JFrame`, this is going to cause no end of issues.  Start with a `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method instead, make you preserve the paint chain by calling it's super method

Comment: Add a series of colors to an array, use `Math.random` to generate a random value between `0` and the arrays `length`, use that as the next color to paint the door

Comment: `The house has a door(rectangle) that randomly changes color with a mouse click` is that a good or a bad thing? I'm guessing it's a bad thing for you, so you need to set the color with `g.setColor(...)` **before** you do any drawing, otherwise it could have the color that was used in a previous component / drawing operation.

Comment: Don't add a listener to a component in a painting method. The painting method is executed every time the component is repainted to you don't want to keep adding listeners.

Comment: stupid solution: replace `g.setColor(Color.black);` with `Random rnd = new Random();g.setColor(new Color(rnd.nextFloat(),rnd.nextFloat(),rnd.nextFloat()));`

Answer (score 3):

Okay, there's a couple of problems that need to be addressed; but hey, what else is StackOverflow for?

1. Every time `paint(Graphics g)` is called, you're creating and assigning a `new MouseEventListener`. Really, this is something you'd only want to do once upon initialization, unless you can forsee multiple `MouseEventListener`s needing to receive updates in future; but even then, you wouldn't want to do it repeatedly in the rendering process anyway; you'd rather do it asynchronously elsewhere. Whatever logic you ever place in any kind of rendering operation, it should only be to do with rendering, or executing tasks that need to be synchronized on each render pass. When you register a `MouseEventListener` on this class, I'm sure you'd want it to receive events for the lifetime of your application; not get constantly overwritten!
2. You're using `setColor(Color.BLACK)` and `setColor(Color.WHITE)`; these are constants! If you want to change the colour, they'll need to become variables. Try placing them as *member variables* in your class, i.e.

   ```
   public final class Final extends JFrame{   
       /* Member Variables. */
       Color mDoorColor  = Color.BLACK;
       Color mHouseColor = Color.WHITE;
   ```

   Then use these colours in your rendering; i.e. `setColor(this.mDoorColor);`. When they're member variables, you can start reading and writing to them; which means that you can persist certain colours for your graphical routines, but also change them as you go! i.e. `this.mHouseColor = Color.CYAN;`
3. When you do create your `MouseListener`, (I suggest making your class **Final** [`implement` the `MouseListener` `interface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)), you can update your values  for `mDoorColor` and `mHouseColor` in there. Then you can assign a [random color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246351/creating-random-colour-in-java) to your random variables.
4. Try better naming conventions. Calling your class **Final** is too similar to a reserved keyword, [`final`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-final-keyword-works). It's not a very helpful name to call your `class`, should anybody else takeover. How about something different, like `MouseHousePainter`? `MouseDrivenHouseDecorator`?
5. Finally, like [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) mentioned, the JFrame is a very powerful graphics class in Java; you don't want to override its `paint` method. Here's a nice [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075417/java-jframe-graphics) of his suggested design approach. *(Not so mad after all, huh.)*

Comment: Lol, "Not so mad after all, huh." Jokes aside, this is a great answer addressing all the right problems and errors.

Answer (score 1):

I have created your program that changes door's color on mouse click.

I added JPanel to draw house and used `Random.nextFloat` to create random color in `paintComponent` method. Like this

```
package com.stackoverflow.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Final extends JFrame {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    JPanel panel;

    public Final() {

        setTitle("An Interactive House");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        super.setSize(500, 500);

        addMouseListener(new MouseEventListener());

        panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                paintHouse(g);
            }
        };
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintHouse(Graphics g) {

        int[] xCoords = { 40, 250, 460 };
        int[] yCoords = { 200, 50, 200 };

        // super.paint(g);

        g.drawRect(80, 200, 330, 260);

        g.drawPolygon(xCoords, yCoords, 3);

        g.setColor(new Color(rnd.nextFloat(), rnd.nextFloat(), rnd.nextFloat()));
        g.fillRect(190, 330, 100, 130);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillOval(280, 400, 5, 5);

    }

    private class MouseEventListener extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            panel.repaint();

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Final();
    }

}
```

I changed `MouseListener` to `MouseAdapter` as you need only `mouseClicked`.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Though when the user open the window, the initial color of the door should be black before the user clicks on the door to change color. How should I approach to fix the code?

Comment: Create class level variable `Color doorColor = Color.BLACK;`. In `paintHouse` method use `g.setColor(doorColor)`. In `MouseEventListener.mouseClicked` write `doorColor = new Color(rnd.nextFloat(), rnd.nextFloat(), rnd.nextFloat())`